# Finding the supremum of a set with two variables

Tags: real-analysis

Let $L = \sup_{x,y \in \mathbb{R} } \frac{ |x + 2y| + 2|y|}{|x| + |y|} $. MY claim is that $L = 4 $

try: can use triangle inequality:

$$  \frac{ |x + 2y| + 2|y|}{|x| + |y|} \leq \frac{ |x| + 2|y| + 2|y| }{|x| + |y|} = \frac{ |x| + 4|y|}{|x|+|y|} \leq 1 + \frac{ 3 |y|}{|x| + |y|} \leq 1 + \frac{ 3 |y|}{|y|} = 1  + 3 = 4$$

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: not yet true, since this means $4$ is an upper bound only. more work is required for it to be the least upper bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly observed that for all $x,y$:

$$L = \sup_{x,y \in \mathbb{R} } \frac{ |x + 2y| + 2|y|}{|x| + |y|} \le 4$$

To show equality all you have to do is show the other inequality, that is, $\ge$. You can do this simply by finding any pair of $x,y$ such that $L \ge 4$:

Take for example $x = 0, y = 1$. Then

$$\frac{ |x + 2y| + 2|y|}{|x| + |y|} = \frac{ | 2| + 2}{1}  = 4$$

Hence certainly,

$$L = \sup_{x,y \in \mathbb{R} } \frac{ |x + 2y| + 2|y|}{|x| + |y|} \ge 4$$